# How to periodically update TreePanel without showing the "updating..." effect?

Tags: extjs

I have a `TreePanel` that I needs to be updated periodically. I'm using the following code on the `ViewController`:

```
'treepanel[name="servers"]' : {
        load: function(self, records, successful, operation, node, eOpts) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                self.reload();
            }, 2500);
        }
 },
```

But every time it reloads, it triggers a "Loading..." message on the panel that flickers for an instant and then shows the updated data.

This is the `TreePanel` code:

```
{
                                xtype : 'treepanel',
                                name : 'servers',
                                id: 'conexao-servers',
                                title : 'Selecione o servidor',
                                flex : 1,
                                overflowY : 'scroll',
                                autoScroll : true,
                                margin : 5,
                                store : Ext.create('Web.store.Servers'),
                                displayField : 'name',
                                rootVisible : false,
                                autoLoad : true,
                                listeners : {
                                    afterrender : function(panel) {
                                        panel.header.insert(panel.header.items.lenght + 1, [
                                            {
                                                xtype : 'button',
                                                name : 'flatView',
                                                text : 'Flat view'
                                            }
                                        ]);
                                    },
                                },
                                bind: {
                                    disabled: '{treeDisabled}'
                                }
                            },
```

That's how it looks like:

[YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FXoITsQM6s)

Is it possible to do it seamlessly, not showing any kind of message or effect, simply updating the data?

I'm using ExtJS 5.1.

Comment: It should not show "Loading..." unless you have `loadMask: true` (by default it is `false`). Do you have it?

Comment: @DrakeES I added the `TreePanel` code to the question. As you can see, I don't have `'loadMask: true`, but it still shows the "Loading..." message.

Comment: Also, setting `loadMask: false` still shows the "Loading..." message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set property **loadMask** to false. It's a sub-property of **viewConfig**.

```
{
   xtype : 'treepanel',
   viewConfig: {
      loadMask: false
   },
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer as it is the solution to the proposed problem: `How to not show the "Loading..." message?"`, but the `TreePanel` still *blinks* as data gets updated. Wish there would be a way to get rid of this blink too.

Comment: It's because your store is flushed, then reloaded. The blink appears during the transition. I think the status of the tree nodes (collapsed/expanded) may also be lost. A better way should be to listen/update only changes, to keep your tree updated, but it's more difficult.